# Lehmann primality test

Tags: java, primes

I'm doing Lehman's test and below function is not giving 100% accurate output. It says all p as prime number. I have been searching and the algorithm seems correct. What could be the issue, please?

```
private static boolean lehmanTest(int p, int tries) {

        boolean isPrime = true;

        int a = randomGenerator();

        int e = (p - 1 )/2;
        int result = (a^e) % p;

        System.out.println ("Result: " + result);

        while (tries!=0)
        {
            if(result % p != 1 && result % p != p - 1)
            {
                a = randomGenerator();
                tries--;
            }
                else
                {
                    isPrime = false;
                }
        }
        return isPrime;
```

### }

Amended code

```
private static boolean lehmanTest(int p, int tries) {

        //boolean isPrime = true;

        //generate random number a
        int a = randomGenerator(p);


        int e = (p - 1 )/2;
        int result = ((int)Math.pow(a,e)) % p;


        while (tries!=0)
        {
            result = ((int)Math.pow(a,e)) % p;


            if(result % p != p - 1)
            //if(result % p != 1 && result % p != p - 1)
            {
                a = randomGenerator(p);             
                tries--;
            }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
        }
        return true;

    }
private static int randomGenerator (int p) {        
        //generate random numbers a, n times        
        Random rand = new Random();

        int randomInt = rand.nextInt(p);
        return randomInt;       
    }
```

Comment: step through in the debugger.....

Answer (score 4):

Your first problem is in this line:

```
    int result = (a^e) % p;
```

a^e is "a xor e" not "a to the eth power". You need Math.pow(a, e) or something equivalent. You should probably re-read the description of the algorithm.

Answer (score 4):

There are three things that should be fixes in your algorithm:

1. Change `int result = (a^e) % p;` to: `int result = ((int)Math.pow(a,e))`% p;
2. Calculate what is now `result` as a randomly chosen set of numbers (right now you are only calculating it for a single randomly generated `a`).
3. Check whether this condition is correct: `result % p != p - 1`
4. Make sure that `randomGenerator()` returns number smaller than `p`.
5. Change `isPrime=false` to: `return false`.

I haven't checked your code implementing these points, I think there might be a problem with what I described in point 3.

Comment: Thanks! I have changed accordingly but now it output every even number > 8 is a prime. Is it because I'm using int?

Comment: I have made changes according to your points. Updated above. Still the same issue. For all even number > 8 is prime.